# Tex in div within div container appears small on small viewport

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling with something that I'm sure is very simple, but above my knowledge or google skills. I'm having multiple pages with text contained in div within div like so:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page title</title>
        <meta name="viewscreen" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div>Banner</div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <p>&emsp;Paragraph text</p>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <p>li item 1</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p>li item 2</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p>li item 3</p>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

When scaling to a small viewport the text appears very tiny if shorter (my guess is that this happens when the text is shorter than div width). I figured out that I can use vw for text size, that appears to be a workaround, but I still can't understand what's the cause of this behavior. Can someone give me a hint how to overcome this problem and what is the potential cause for it?

Thanks in advance,

Assen

Comment: how did you define the font-size? Are you using some custom font? Please share the minimal css too.

Comment: Use Css to style the size of the Div or Text

Comment: I found out that it's not related to the css it happens with or without css involved. I normally use em to define the font-size, but even if I increase the em for the pages I talk about, is not changing anything. It appears, that only when I define the font-size in vw the font is scaling correctly. Perhaps I must create a separate style for those divs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add meta tag with name `viewport`, I don't think `viewscreen` is a valid meta tag name. That should fix the problem.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: YES! Thanks a lot. That's the fix. I new it's something simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```